# start on vagrant-mounted (upstart) equivalent in systemd

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, upstart, systemd

I have a Vagrant box running Ubuntu 15.04, which has an upstart script that starts a service when the system boots. It has a `start on vagrant-mounted` stanza because the service requires that the /vagrant directory be mounted by Vagrant.

I am now migrating this script to systemd (which I am completely new to) and cannot get the script to successfully run during boot because /vagrant is not mounted when the script is run. `After=vagrant-mounted` doesn't work, but might help show what I'm trying to do.

**How do I run a systemd unit when a Vagrant directory has been mounted during boot?**

Note `systemctl start my.service` *does* successfully start the service, and the service is `systemctl enabled`'ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of the Vagrant boot sequence is that Vagrant mounts `/vagrant` (and any other shared filesystems you have defined) using SSH, after the boot sequence has completed.

As such, you'll probably want to run `systemctl start my.service` in a provisioner, with [`run: always`](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html) specified, so the provisioner runs on every boot, not just when the VM is initially created.

This wouldn't be necessary if systemd had the ability to detect when a filesystem was mounted, but to my surprise I can't find any indication that systemd supports such functionality.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion myself; if the script is simple enough, it has been recommended to just put it in its own bash script and run it with `run: 'always'` like you said. Of course, this works if systemd specific functionality isn't needed.